# legit to adjust tableView bounds to desplay single section?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, bounds

I appologize if this information is readily available, as it is late and am wanting to take shortcuts. Instead of messing with all of the backing data and reloading the tableView, is there anything wrong with recalculating the bounds of a UITableView to show a single section?

I have a grouped section with a start and end date range, that when you select a row a datePicker animates in from the bottom of the screen. I change the navigationItems during this mode to "cancel" and "done", however in doing so it doesnt make sence to allow editing of information in other sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, resizing of table views is done all the time.  Another common reason to resize table views is when the keyboard comes up.

You can also disable scrolling if you do not want them to move out of the area they are in.

Comment: I do adjust the frame when the keyboard is shown, but I believe I need to adjust the bound rect this time. I would like to disable scrolling but in landscape mode the section is partially hidden.